# How to compile rtaudio with QT?

Tags: qt, compilation, linker-errors, libraries, rtaudio

I need to install the real time proccess library "rtaudio-4.1.1" on windows in order to use it in C++ projet.

I'd try to compile the library project given by MIT website with QTCreator. I opened the qt project RTaudio and click on compile and the output is:

```
In function `newDrvStruct` (in asiolist.o):
undefined reference to `_imp__CLSIDFromString@8' in asiolist.cpp

In function `ZN14AsioDriverListC2Ev` (in asiolist.o):
undefined reference to `_imp__CoInitialize@4' in asiolist.cpp
```

Some research on the subject leads me to accuse the linker configuration but I didn't know very well what's the problem and how to solve it. :'(

So, i'm calling you to give me some hope !

Thanks by advance ! =)

Comment: Where did you download that Qt project? Do you mean project of the library or a project that uses that library?

Comment: The QT project is given with library files and seems to be made to compile the library.

Comment: I mean URL that was used to download the project and details about build steps. If I download `rtaudio-4.1.1` package there is no any Qt project file. There are CMake files that can be opened in Qt Creator.

Comment: I have download at https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/.
I understood that there is a project in the folder named "RTaudio/" present in the folder "rtaudio-4.1.1/". There is a  .pro and a QT project file.
Am I wrong ?

Comment: That is strange because I cannot find any `.pro` file in http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/release/rtaudio-4.1.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

The "ole32.dll" lib is missing. Try to add this to your .pro file:

`LIBS += -lole32 -lwinmm -luuid -lksuser`